# Apply condition to window function in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Say that I have this data:

```
status   |  source |  communication
-------------------|----------------
start    |  1      |  1
changed  |  2      |  1
changed  |  2      |  1
changed  |  2      |  1
end      |  1      |  1
```

I know that I can use the lag function partitioning on the communication column and ordering by a timestamp column (not shown here) to get the previous source.

However, I how do I get the previous source where the `status is not 'Changed'` while retaining all the rows? Like this:

```
status   |  source |  communication | prev_source
-------------------|----------------|-----------
start    |  1      |  1             | null
changed  |  2      |  1             | 1
changed  |  2      |  1             | 1
changed  |  2      |  1             | 1
end      |  1      |  1             | 1
```

Comment: Your question should include the column used for ordering the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `ignore nulls`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(case when status <> 'changed' then source end ignore nulls) over
           (order by ??) as prev_source
from t;
```

You also need a column to specify the ordering of the rows.  That is what the `??` is for.

Comment: Hi! this does the trick if there is only one row that has the status of changed, what if there are multiple rows with status 'changed' between 'start' and 'end'?

Comment: @rodrigocf . . . Oops, I left `ignore nulls` out of the code.